# Thread Safety: JFrame and another class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety

I have two threads a JFrame and a listener.

The listener is actively listening for messages from the server and appending to the message box in the JFrame accordingly. Currently I have the JFrame passed into the listener and calling the JFrames `appendMessageBox` method I have created inside the listen thread.

Should I synchronize the method `appendMessageBox` with the listener thread? Should I make the listener's methods a callback in the JFrames thread?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is simple: all calls that modify Swing components should be made on the Swing event thread, the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). Period.

So, your listener should update a model on the event dispatch thread, and the model change should be reflected in the JFrame (the view).